# Weighed numpys random.choice for intervals

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to create, pseudo-randomly, an array of transaction values from half-open intervals, for example `[1,5), [5,10), [10,25)` and so on. Each number in the interval has the same chance to be picked, but I want to adjust the probability of getting some intervals over others. The flow should look like this way:

```
1: Pick any of the defined intervals > Pick a random number in the interval > Append number in array
2: Pick any of the defined intervals > Pick a random number in the interval > Append number in array
...
n: Pick any of the defined intervals > Pick a random number in the interval > Append number in array
```

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
# set interval limits
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = 1,5,10,25,50,100,200,300,500,1000
# start picking random numbers
np.random.seed(33)
trx_value = np.random.choice([np.random.uniform(a,b), 
                              np.random.uniform(b,c),
                              np.random.uniform(c,d),
                              np.random.uniform(d,e),
                              np.random.uniform(e,f),
                              np.random.uniform(f,g),
                              np.random.uniform(g,h),
                              np.random.uniform(h,i),
                              np.random.uniform(i,j)], 20, 
                              p=[0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02])
trx_value
```

It seems that it is working in a different way, as the result is not displaying the uniqueness in the values I was expecting:

```
> array([  8.22611761,   8.22611761, 127.05325134,   8.22611761,
>        266.53172436,  35.43526485,  35.43526485,  88.57366253,
>        127.05325134,  12.38946805, 266.53172436, 127.05325134,
>         12.38946805,  35.43526485, 127.05325134,  12.38946805,
>        266.53172436,   8.22611761])
```

It seems it is doing something like this:

```
1: For each interval, pick a random number > Store this number in a pool
2: Pick a random number from the pool > Append number in array
...
n: Pick a random number from the pool > Append number in array
```

I am sure it is a thinking-problem, but I want to know if this is possible without using a `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all distributions you wish to pick from are uniform, I would suggest the following setup.

```
interval_p = np.array([0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.02])
interval_lo = np.array([1,5,10,25,50,100,200,300,500])
interval_hi = np.concatenate([lo[1:], [1000]])
interval_width = interval_hi - interval_lo

n = 20
c = np.random.choice(len(interval_p), p=interval_p, size=n)
results = interval_lo[c] + np.random.uniform(size=n) * interval_width[c]
```

This works because we can rescale the uniform distribution `r` on `[0, 1]` to any uniform distribution on `[a, b]` using `a + r*(b-a)`.

Comment: You can just make `interval = np.array([1,5,10,25,50,100,200,300,500,1000])` and then have `interval_width = np.diff(interval)` and use `interval[:-1]` instead of `interval_lo`.  Makes it a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks! It works, and with @DanielF recommendations is even more readable. You can say when you are dealing with guys with strong mathematical background :)